# When to add an index to a SQL table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table called `Foo` that has two columns `A` and `B`. Both of these columns are foreign keys to two other tables. These columns together make up the primary key, and it has a clustered index for this primary key by default.

My question is... does it benefit me at all to have another non-clustered index for `B`? Or is this unnecessary?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Product specific question.)

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: It could, yes. It depends on what your query predicates are and how this table is being used. You need to provide more info. Also, have any of your queries given you a missing index hint?

Comment: Will you ever or often query the table knowing only the B value?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn it's very often the table is only getting queried by B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, some background, to make sure we're on the same page.

It sounds like you have also have tables `Bar`, with `A` as the key, and `Baz`, with `B` as the key, where the `Foo` table maintains a many-to-many intersection relationship between `Bar` and `Baz`, like this:

```
Bar(A) <=> Foo(A,B) <=> Baz(B)
```

If that's true, you need to ask yourself how you'll use the relationship. If you will start from `Bar` more often, and then need to discover related `Baz` values, then the primary (clustered) key should be `(A, B)`. If you'll start from `Baz` more often, and then need to get the `Bar` values, then the primary key should be `(B, A)`.

For this question, we are given the `(A, B)` situation, and asked whether an additional `(B, A)` key is a good idea. So we should assume you will more often start from a `Bar` record and need to know related `Baz` records: `Bar -> Foo -> Baz`, or at worst it's 50/50.

---

Now to answer the question.

The additional `(B, A)` index (or even just [`(B) INCLUDES A`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-indexes-with-included-columns?view=sql-server-2017)) *may* be helpful if you will also sometimes start from a `Baz` record and need to know related `Bar` records (`Baz -> Foo -> Bar`)... when you have queries going through `Foo` in both directions.

But it's also important to remember additional indexes have storage, memory, and maintenance costs. Whether the additional index will have a net-positive impact on your application depends on if you will use this kind of lookup often enough to overcome those costs. It's also worth mentioning the costs will be higher if the table changes often, because every change must now also update both indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot say for sure without some detailed knowledge of your database workload.  It will depend upon your usage.

If you query a lot from B to the shared table then its likely having an index on B will help.  There are various tools you can use to see if you should optimise your indices based upon your workload including the Database Engine Tuning Advisor that comes with SQL Server.

Additionally if you have a referential integrity constriant on the B foreign key it generally helps to also have an index.

btw I am assuming your primary key is A followed by B and is the clustered index.  Therefore the clustered index handles A and there is no need to have a separate index on A.

Comment: Ok.. sorry I have another question with this answer. If it was "B followed by A", then I don't need another index for only B? How does the order of the primary key make a difference?

Comment: I am assuming the Primary key is also the clustered index on the table.  If so the rows will be saved in the order of the tuple (A,B) which means that SQL server knows the range where all rows with A are

Comment: per PhilS' answer you can look at the execution plan of the query and if an index IS missing Sql server will suggest it to you Ron. But keep in mind what @Joel has said top side that indexes have cost. Someone has to rebuild and re-index them from time to time (be you or a DBA).